# Java String to date parsing error, how to do it properly

Tags: java, date, io

I am interested to know if my code is correct and it doesn't have any issues. Date is taken from binary file, written as a string in such format YYYY-MM-DD/Hours-minutes-seconds example: 2022-01-23/12:00:00.

Program was meant to check date if it's expiring or expired, add it to proper list and display it after loops end.

```
public static void expiration_date(String filepath){
        try {
            DataInputStream read = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(filepath));
            DateTimeFormatter format_day = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd");
            DateTimeFormatter format_hour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDate now_day = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDateTime now_hour = LocalDateTime.now();
            ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> expire_in_week = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> expire_tomorrow = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> expire_today = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> expired = new ArrayList<>();
            while(read.available()>0) {
                String name = read.readUTF();
                String surname = read.readUTF();
                String date = read.readUTF();
                String cardcode = read.readUTF();
                String cardtype = read.readUTF();
                int contract_num = read.readInt();
                String cert_num = read.readUTF();
                String phone_num = read.readUTF();
                String email = read.readUTF();
                String status = read.readUTF();
                String comment = read.readUTF();
                dates.add(date);
                for (String s:dates){
                    String[] data = s.split("/");

                    String days =data[0];
                    LocalDate date_days = LocalDate.parse(days.replace("-", "/"), format_day);

                    String hours =data[1];
                    LocalTime date_hours = LocalTime.parse(hours.replace("-", ":"),format_hour);


                    long daysbetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now_day,date_days);
                    long hoursbetween = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(now_hour,date_hours);
                    if (daysbetween==7){
                        expire_in_week.add(cert_num);
                    }else if (daysbetween==1){
                        expire_tomorrow.add(cert_num);
                    }else if (daysbetween==0 && hoursbetween>0){
                        expire_today.add(cert_num);
                    }else if (daysbetween<0 || (daysbetween==0 && hoursbetween<0)){
                        expired.add(cert_num);
                    }else{}


                }
            }

            System.out.println("Certificates that expires:");
            System.out.println("Next week");
            for (String w:expire_in_week){
                System.out.print(w+"|");
            }
            System.out.println("Tomorrow");
            for (String tm:expire_tomorrow){
                System.out.print(tm+"|");
            }
            System.out.println("Today");
            for (String td:expire_today){
                System.out.print(td+"|");
            }
            System.out.println("Today");
            for (String ex:expired){
                System.out.print(ex+"|");
            }


        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        catch(IOException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    }
```

When i start it i got error message returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 12:00 of type java.time.LocalTime
at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:463)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.until(LocalDateTime.java:1677)
at java.base/java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.between(ChronoUnit.java:272)
at com.company.program.expiration_date(program.java:189)
at com.company.program.main(program.java:364)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: 12:00 of type java.time.LocalTime
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:398)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:458)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: can you add the file content please ?

Comment: @Alejandro Gonzalez content: name-surname-date-cardcode-cardtype-contractnum-certificatenum-phone-email-status-commnet
Everything written with writeUTF except contract number

Comment: attach this information in the question

Comment: which line is `program.java:189`. BTW java naming conventions says, that class name should start with upper case character. And use camelCase names not `_`

Comment: @Jens long hoursbetween = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(now_hour,date_hours);

Comment: Looks like between needs a complete date not only the time part

Comment: @Jens Really? Even thought i only want to compare hours? I will try and see

Comment: @Jens I figured out how to fix it, i changed LocalDateTime now_hour = LocalDateTime.now(); to Localtime and it works

Comment: Tip: Educate the publisher of your input data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard that defines formats for representing date-time values as text. No need to invent formats. The standard format uses COLON as separator in time portion, and uses a LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T  (`T`) to separate the date portion from time portion: `2022-01-23T12:00:00`. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern: `LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-01-23T12:00:00" )`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because date_hours is of type LocalDateTime and date_hours is of type LocalTime. Try using the same type for both.

```java
LocalTime now_hour = LocalTime.now();
```

Side note to parse the values of LocalDate and LocalTime you can try this

```java
String data = "2022-01-23/12-00-00";
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd/HH-mm-ss");

LocalDate dateDays = LocalDate.parse(data, dateTimeFormatter);
LocalTime dateHours = LocalTime.parse(data, dateTimeFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

See working example of your code here: https://github.com/RobbingDaHood/answers/blob/master/so70824574/src/Main.java

You `LocalTime date_hours` needs a timezone before it can be compared with `LocalDateTime now_hour`. So either add one to date_hours as I did in the code or remove the one from now_hour.

In my code the date_hours would get the system timezone, as the code is now. Be aware that maybe your file is not using that timezone.

## Output of the example code is:

Certificates that expires:
Next week
Tomorrow
Today
Today
Cert1|

## You can read more here

https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro
That will give you a good intro to the different date types in Java.